# Some sites can not be proxied? How ist this behaviour achieved?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I was having trouble configuring an nginx reverse proxy within my development environment when I stumbled on a behaviour that I do not quite get.

So nginx is listening on port 8080. When I make a request to my development-server, I can access my development server on

```
localhost:8080
```

**With the following directives:**

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  site.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

But when I put a known website in the proxy `pass_directive` like google or apple the behaviour is different. I can not access e. g. apple.com as localhost:8080 with the following directives - I am immediately pushed to the real website and not the localhost:

```
server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  site.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://apple.com/;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
```

**How is that behaviour called and how is it achieved?** Can you guys put me in the right direction to understanding this? Thanks.

Comment: That's what I'd expect to happen with the above config. Perhaps your [`proxy_redirect`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) directive should instead be set to `on`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behavior for the proxy service, you can find docs here https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Some information regarding proxies here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Example: if you want to go to http://apple.com/apple-card/, you can point out to localhost:8080/apple-card and you will be redirected to /requested_path

I'm using proxies with docker containers just to route the requests to the correct application using different ports.